# How to select all similar nodes to a given DOM Node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am building a UI component where the user comes and higlights a portion of a HTML page and the component should identify all "visually similar" elements to the selected one and highlight them as well . E.g the user selects one story link in "Hacker News" or a single question in "StackOverflow" site main pages and system should be able to identify all other similar links from this.
      Currently I can do this from css selector strings of 2 selected items purely by string manipulation on these strings and coming up with a generic selector.
       Wondering how the approach would be different if given 1 node instead of 2
**EDIT** - By "visually similar" I mean similar text nodes. In the example of Hacker News website above it will be other text nodes with similar style having a recurring structure in their cssSelector path e.g the set of story titles, ranks , source url , author name etc. Or text in a column of a table etc.

Comment: What is `visually similar` to you? same classes, sizes, attrs, params, texts etc?

Comment: "[...] the component should identify all "visually similar" elements to the selected one and highlight them as well." Surely this is exactly what CSS `class` is for, no? In which case, simply use `var similarElements = getElementsByClassName('similar-elements-class');` to create your nodelist.

Comment: @Rounin the problem is in isolating the unique css class. What if the css class is not unique? So I was thinking more in lines of cssSelector kind of notation something like `"html > body > div:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(4) > div .... > a"`